# CSS Gradient Text for 2022

Tags: css, gradient

I have implemented all the CSS I can find to make this work but it still appears white on iOS.
Works fine in Chrome, Edge and Firefox.

What am I missing?
Can YOU see the gradient headings on this page? https://hydrogreenlawns.com/

Here is what calls it:

```css
.gradient-text-Green {
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#AFF31E, #60EF04);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px #00000000;
}


/*! elementor - v3.5.5 - 03-02-2022 */
.elementor-heading-title {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  line-height: 1
}

.elementor-widget-heading .elementor-heading-title[class*=elementor-size-]>a {
  color: inherit;
  font-size: inherit;
  line-height: inherit
}

.elementor-widget-heading .elementor-heading-title.elementor-size-small {
  font-size: 15px
}

.elementor-widget-heading .elementor-heading-title.elementor-size-medium {
  font-size: 19px
}

.elementor-widget-heading .elementor-heading-title.elementor-size-large {
  font-size: 29px
}

.elementor-widget-heading .elementor-heading-title.elementor-size-xl {
  font-size: 39px
}

.elementor-widget-heading .elementor-heading-title.elementor-size-xxl {
  font-size: 59px
}
```

```html
<div class="elementor-element elementor-element-d5fc70e gradient-text-Green elementor-widget elementor-widget-heading" data-id="d5fc70e" data-element_type="widget" data-widget_type="heading.default">
  <div class="elementor-widget-container">
    <h1 class="elementor-heading-title elementor-size-xl">BENEFITS OF HYDROSEEDING</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Works fine in [codepen](https://codepen.io/PavelSchiller/pen/abVJaQe). Give us more code, not just a link to a website, and maybe we can help you.

Comment: Sure, thank you. Adding it above.

Comment: It works fine in Chrome, Edge and Firefox, just not Safari. I don't know whether codepen tests for that.